# Browser and download VisualPage renderas pdf

Tags: browser

I have one visual page render as PDF and one custom button in standard List view page. One controller use :

```
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id').split('\\,');
```

to get id from Url.

- With Chrome : 
  when I click custom button to preview my page my controller was called two time(only Chrome). 
  If custom button call my visual page and don't sent selected record's id to URL.In the first time I can use getSelected() method to get selected record's id, but in the second time controller run, it can't get id of selected record, so I can't download PDF.

The problem is :

- With Internet Explorer :　
  If there is more than 120 record was selected and sent it's id to URL, my browser can't handle it.

Please tell me , how should I do. any other way to create custom bottom or o other way to get selected record's Id ?

thanks you !!!

EDITED :

thanks Saumya Ranjan Satapathy.

1. my first screen when I selected records from standard list view
2. my second screen is after I click to my ご請求 button and put id to my URL I can download with no problem
3. my third screen is after I click to my ご請求 button and "didn't" put my Id to My URL and I can't download my PDF file because with no pdf extenstion.
   [[image: first screen]

[image: sconder]
[image: third]

Comment: Can you put an example of wht you are getting and wht you expect?